# Dropbox sync icons not showing up on Dropbox folder and files in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I've installed Dropbox for Linux following the instructions given here 
https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux

Dropbox seems to be running and syncing fine; however I don't see the sync status icons on my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `nautilus-dropbox` package installed. Run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox
```

Then log out and log in again.